# "Failed to initialize the GameStartup Interface" when trying to run Crysis 2 demo

Tags: steam, crysis-2

I've downloaded the Crysis 2 demo through Stream, but when I try to run it I immediately get the error message

> Failed to initialize the GameStartup Interface!

and nothing happens after clicking the "OK" button. What causes this problem, and how can I fix it?

System specifications:

- Windows 7 64bit.
- Nvidia Geforce 250 GTS, with latest drivers.
- All other PC stats also matching or exceeding minimum requirements as specified in the Steam Store page.

Comment: Please provide more Info: OS, GPU, current drivers, any overclocked component etc.

Comment: Agreeing with Bora. We need more information. Additionnaly, did you verify the game fragmentation, through the game options? You could consider suppressing crysis2 .gcf, then re-DL it, it could resolve your problem...

Comment: The GPU seems a little faint for this monster of a game.

Comment: @Lysarion verifying file integrity has solved the problem; please migrate your comment to an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Added answer. I also put some details about potential origins. It may need a spellchecking, i fear i made some errors, since i'm french... Could you check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of error can sometimes be solved when you verify the game fragmentation, through the game options.

Game fragmentation usually happens when you download too many games at once through Steam, or when a game is being downloaded by too many people at once.

It can also be caused by running a process which does a lot of disk access.

Comment: It wasn't precisely a fragmentation problem... but choosing "verify integrity of game cache" in Steam fixed the error.

Comment: Yup, but usually (at least with source-engine based games), interface-initialization's problems come from highly fragmented game files, and asking Steam to chek fragmentation also forces a presence-check for all of the game files. That's why i was suggesting it in the first time, since it could have resolved those two problems.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. This is how I fixed it:

Copy all .dll files from the "bin32" directory and paste them in the main directory.