# Stuck on "Starting in 1..." in Crysis 2 demo

Tags: crysis-2

I just downloaded the Crysis 2 demo via Steam.  It launches ok, showed an intro movie, and lists a bunch of servers to join.  However, every time I join a game it does the 60 second count down and gets stuck on the last second.  The chat goes 'silent' so I figure maybe other folks are playing the game successfully, leaving me to guard the lobby :)

Anyone else getting this?  Any ideas?

**Edit** Looks like [this guy](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960489-crysis-2/58305455/646680860) is having the same issue, though no answer over there.

Comment: For starters I would verify the game files integrity, [it worked for me](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17541/failed-to-initialize-the-gamestartup-interface-when-trying-to-run-crysis-2-demo) when encountering a weird issue :)

Comment: Aw, i was going to say the same... =)

Comment: @Oak, @Lysarion, cheers -- just tried that.  It didn't say anything was amiss, but I'll give it a shot and see.  Have also rebooted.

Comment: Win to verification of game cache again \o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some combination of rebooting and verifying the integrity of the game cache via Steam sorted it out.